# Cannot connect to my AWS RDS instance from my local computer using python socket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, cloud, chat

This code works when connecting from my computer to another computer on the same network.

However, when transferring the server code to the AWS instance with a public IP address, the
server code doesn't work.

I put a private IPv4 address also, it doesn't work:

```
import socket
HOST = "Client IP"
PORT = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.sendall(data)
    s.close()
```

Client code:

```
import socket
HOST = "Server IP"
PORT = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
s.close()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)? They're important. Also, when you say "RDS instance" I guess you mean EC2, not RDS.

Comment: Yes, I mean, AWS, what do I do with my security group?

Comment: If you're not familiar with security groups (which are essentially virtual firewalls) then that's likely to be your problem. I'd recommend an introductory resource such as [AWS Essentials: Security Groups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9j7BvAyb2w). To allow inbound traffic to port 5555 on an EC2 instance, you need to create a security group with the relevant ingress rule (allow inbound IPv4 TCP on port 5555 from 0.0.0.0/0, for example), and associate that security group with the EC2 instance. By default, traffic to the instance is blocked.

Comment: I modified my security group and the problem still persists
When I run the code on my PC and put the public address, the error appears
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: Is that error from calling bind on your server? I would check what IP addresses are available to you on the server and bind to the correct one.

Comment: There are a public address and private on the server side. When using the public address of the server, the error appears on the server side
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context .
 and When using the private address, the error appears on the client side after a few seconds
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by opening a port on the router for the client computer
I also put the IP in the HOST variable in the server code is 0.0.0.0
and the IP in the client code was set by the public IP of the server